# Trying to sum MySQL value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sum my MySQL column value with number, here is my php script, i dont think im doing in right way. I was searching in stackoweflow but i havent found how to sum with specific number, not with other column.

```
<?php
$currentUser = isset($_POST['currentUser']) ? $_POST['currentUser'] : '';
$currentTasken = isset($_POST['currentTasken']) ? $_POST['currentTasken'] : '';
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$con)
        die('Could not connectzzz: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("foxi" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_task_log");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if($numrows >= 1)
    {
        //$pass = md5($pass);

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dotp_task_log (task_log_creator, task_log_Task) VALUES ('$currentUser' , '$currentTasken')" ) ;

        if($ins)
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_task WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
            if($numrows == 1)
            {
                //$pass = md5($pass);

                    $ins = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT SUM(task_percent_complete) FROM dotp_task WHERE task_id='$currentTasken') FirstSum, (SELECT SUM(5)), SecondSum ");

                   if($ins)
                        die("Succesfully summed!");

                    else
                        die("ERROR");

            }
            else
            {
                die("Cant sum!");
            }           
            die("Succesfully Created Log!");


        else
            die("ERROR");

    }
    else
    {
        die("Log already exists!");
    }


?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `from` clause in your second query.

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated, please switch to `msqli` or `pdo`. Alsi, your `insert` query is missing all kinds of data, the top level of the query is selecting fields but you didn't tell it from what resource, there's no where clause, and you have trailing white space as well.

Comment: `$ins = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT SUM(task_percent_complete) FROM dotp_task WHERE task_id='$currentTasken') FirstSum, (SELECT SUM(5)), SecondSum ");` This line still isn't a fully qualified MySQL query, it's missing the `from` selector and any `where` clause.

Comment: I edited here: https://jsfiddle.net/7vudjn8m/ but it doesnt add these 5...

Comment: Maby i should somehow insert value which summed back to database with insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not written properly. Try to run this query from `MySQL` command line or from PHPMyAdmin. It will give you an idea what the error is. My best guess is that the first part of the query is not complete.

This is what it will resolve to

```
SELECT n FirstSum, 5, SecondSum
```

Where `n` is the value returned from the subquery. This is a syntax error. Try to remove the last comma before `SecondSum`.
This is what your query should be:

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(task_percent_complete)
        FROM   dotp_task
        WHERE  task_id = '$currentTasken') FirstSum,
       (SELECT Sum(5))                     SecondSum
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
(select sum(5))
```

and replace it with

```
(select 5)
```